# Turn a forEach function into a reduce function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been asked to refactor the following code:

```
  const temp = {};
  this.sessionData = [];
  sessionsData.forEach(session => {
    const date = moment(session.startDatetime).format('DDMMYYYY');
    if (temp[date]) {
      temp[date].push(session);
    } else {
      temp[date] = [session];
    }
  });
```

Apparently it can be more efficient using reduce?

I have tried to simply place reduce in the function but this isnt good enough ;)

```
  const temp = {};
  this.sessionData = [];
  sessionsData.reduce(session => {
    const date = moment(session.startDatetime).format('DDMMYYYY');
    if (temp[date]) {
      temp[date].push(session);
    } else {
      temp[date] = [session];
    }
  });
```

I understand reduce can add the elements together and have other fun stuff happen during the process BUT specifically I have been asked to sort of get rid of my variables and use them within reduce I suppose!

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to refactor this using reduce, you have to set an inital value `{}` for the accumulator, and then you have to modify this accumulator, this is what `reduce` will return after the iterations on your data. You then have to assign this returned accumulator to your `temp` variable.

So the only input you give to reduce is `sessionData`, on which reduce is applied. Then at each iteration, it gives you the `session` and you modify `accum`.
Also, make sure to return this `accum` at the end of each iteration, since it has to be passed to the next iteration.

[Here is the MDN doc on reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```
const temp = sessionData.reduce((accum, session) => {
    const date = moment(session.startDatetime).format('DDMMYYYY');
    if (accum[date]) {
        accum[date].push(session);
    } else {
        accum[date] = [session];
    }
    return accum;
}, {});
```

Comment: look that reduce returns a new array, then the original array will not touched so you are skipping some side effects.

Comment: better use [] than object {} in your reduce @jo_va

Comment: Of course, note that `temp` on the inside of the function is *not* the same `temp` you have on the outside. Personally, as a matter of clarity, I would change names.

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón `reduce` doesn't return an array. Why do you think it's better to work with arrays in this case, anyway?

Comment: @Álvaro Touzón, temp is an object not an array, according to what is in the question

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, bug mine i assume uses an Array, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
let dates = [{startDatetime: '2016-01-02'}, {startDatetime: '2016-02-02'}, {startDatetime: '2016-03-02'}];

const temp = dates.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
  const date = moment(cur.startDatetime).format('DDMMYYYY');
  if(acc[date]) acc[date].push(cur)
  else acc[date] = [cur]
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use in es6

```js
var sessionData = [
{foo:'bar', startDatetime: Date.now()},
{xxx:'yyy', startDatetime: Date.now()}
];

console.log(
  sessionData.reduce((obj,next) => {
      const key = moment(sessionData.startDatetime).format('DDMMYYYY');
      if(!obj[key]) obj[key] = [];
      obj[key].push(next);
      return obj;
 },{})
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```